# Making Sprite respond to mouse clicks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a scene (SKScene), in which, whenever a click is performed a ball (SKSprtieNode) is dropped from that point.
Now what I want to do is, whenever a click on the ball is performed, the ball should bounce or something.

What I have in GameScene.m is

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
   CGPoint location = [theEvent locationInNode:self];
   [self addBallAtLocation:location];
}

- (void)addBallAtLocation:(CGPoint) location {
   Ball *ball = [Ball new];

   ball.position = location;
   [self addChild:ball];
}
```

And in Ball.m I add the bounce action to mouseDown method:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
   CGPoint point = [theEvent locationInNode:self];

   CGVector impulse = CGVectorMake(point.x * 5.0, point.y * 5.0);

   [self.physicsBody applyImpulse:impulse];
}
```

Right now a new ball is created even when clicked on a exiting ball. I thought that the ball's mouseDown method would be called since I clicked on it, and if that did not exist the scene's mouseDown method would be called.

P.S. I have a feeling that this could be solved with delegate, I could very easily be wrong, but since I am not totally clear on to use them, I didn't. If you think that might be a good way to resolve this issue, please do use them, as it may help me understand how to use them.

Comment: Have you tried setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on your Ball object ? (by default `SKSpriteNOde` set that thing to `NO`, certainly for performance reasons)

Comment: @ddr2 Yep, that was it. Thanks, if you wanna write that an answer, I will select it for answering the question.

Comment: Not really after points but if someone gets here, I think he will not look at the comments for the answer and will just assume there was no solution :/ So I've wrote an answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `SKSpriteNode` has its `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `NO` (certainly for performance reasons). You simply have to set it to `YES` and your event-handling methods will be called :)